# App is loading each time

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash

I have web application of flex. It's swf file is attached on a tabview. Means there are 5 tabs on the page. On the tab Five a swf file is attached.

When I click on five tab it load the init method of main mxml file of flex application. Is there any way so we can stop to load it every time when we click on Five tab.

[image]

This app get the data from server when load the application. But I don't want to send the request again and again when click on tab everytime.

Comment: Can you include a code snip of how you are loading the external SWF?

Comment: <div id="tabs-5">
  <div id="swfDiv" style="display:none;">
   <object id='xyzSwf' classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' codebase='http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab' height='200' width='400'>
    <param name='src' value=''/>
    <param name='flashVars' value="" />
    <embed name='xyzSwf' src='' pluginspage='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer' height='100%' width='100%' flashVars=""/>
   </object>
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: src attribute is set dynamically by javascript code.

Comment: How are you hiding / showing the various tabs?

Comment: I am using jquery function for this :-

$(function() {
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});

Here is Html code for all tabs.

<li><a href="#tabs-1">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Three</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-4">Four</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-5">Five</a></li>

Answer (score 0):

Using <a href=""> to display your tabs is probably making them reload with each click. Instead try a script solution to set the `display` value of each tab. Loop through them all and hide every one except the one clicked on.

This way you only load them once.

EDIT: looks like you are using JQuery. Some possible answers:

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952020/javascript-hide-show-tabs-using-jquery)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324887/javascript-show-hide-tab)
- [here (not jquery)](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/172884/javascript-showhide-tabs)